# Combining relations on a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

This is the statement that I need to prove:

> Let R and S be two relations on set U, of which R is transitive and S is reflexive. Prove that: (R;S;R)^3 is a subset of (R;S)^3.

The obvious way to prove this is to: assume some x that is the element of (R;S;R)^2 and prove that it is also element of (R;S)^3. However, I have no idea how to do this, or how to use the properties of transitivity and reflexivity to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Cheers :)

Comment: What does the notation $(R;S;R)^3$ and $(R;S)^3$ mean?

Comment: $(R;S:R)$ is, I think, the composition of $R$ $S$ and $R$ in order (the standard composition for relations), powers are self-compositions.

Comment: Exactly as @HennoBrandsma said.